# react native touchable click for Android and ios conditional

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create multiple instances with touchable-click for Android and ios and I'm having trouble figuring out where to place the conditional I keep getting errors for unexpected token. I want to set a conditional where if the app is on android switch to touchablenativefeedback and if not stay with touchableopacity.

```
 {Platform.OS === 'android' ?
        <TouchableNativeFeedback
          onPress={gotoedit}
          style={{ justifyContent: 'center'}}
        >
            <View>
                <Entypo
                  name={'edit'}
                  size={22}
                  color={Colors.offWhite}
                  style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }}
                />
                {/* <View
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: 0,
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    justifyContent: 'left',
                    alignItems: 'left',
                  }}
                >
                  <Text style={{ color: Colors.offWhite, fontWeight: '600' }}>{UnreadNotifications && UnreadNotifications.length}</Text>
                </View> */}
            </View>

          </TouchableNativeFeedback>
          :
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={gotoedit}
            style={{ justifyContent: 'center'}}
          >
              <View>
                  <Entypo
                    name={'edit'}
                    size={22}
                    color={Colors.offWhite}
                    style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }}
                  />
                  {/* <View
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: 0,
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                      borderRadius: 10,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      justifyContent: 'left',
                      alignItems: 'left',
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text style={{ color: Colors.offWhite, fontWeight: '600' }}>{UnreadNotifications && UnreadNotifications.length}</Text>
                  </View> */}
              </View>

            </TouchableOpacity>
          }
    );
```

Comment: this is within a component by the way

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: unexpected token expected,

Comment: I guess the ternary operator is causing the issue. can you try like `if (Platform.OS === 'ios')
  return (
    <SomeIOSComponent />
)
else
  return (
    <SomeAndroidComponent />
)` and see whether any error? if not the second and third param  of ternary should evaluate i guess

Comment: ok thanks im going to try it and let you know

Comment: Ternary operators should not cause any issue like this. Can you post the code for your component? Because from what i can see the only thing out of place is the last ');'